# Why does Teleriks Tabs Control only works after a postback in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radpanelbar

I have RadTabPanel1 in my page using a MasterPage, when i click on a tabpanel, it will add # to the address bar (eg: localhost:8080/SiBase/Default.aspx#).
Until i trigger a postback from button or any other control before the tab opens. This works fine in a normal page (without masterpage).

Please what can I do to resolve this issue? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an Ajax Extenders that was not in use which was causing postback problems, I just removed them and it worked fine. Thanks